# Unexpected token < Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
Unexpected token < {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}
```

I would like to call an Ajax function but i got this error instead ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url     :'index.php?module=Page&action=Mandats',
            type    : 'post',
            timeout : 3000,
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function (data, status, xhr){ 
                alert(status);
                },
            error   : function (xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Do you know why that ?

Comment: This error means that the URL you're calling is returning HTML, not JSON. Usually this is because of a 404 or 500 error on the server. Check the network tab of the console to see what the exact response is.

Comment: aaaaah yeah the URL is nt yet finished... but i was thinking that i might have an error on my js... Thank you :)

Comment: What is the data that you're passing in?

Comment: I'm not passing any data except with the URL,  I deleted the ligne data. In fact I want to refresh content with new data every x second...